# Command with argument and several results inside command (inside command...)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expl3, parsing, arguments

I want to reuse a command that performs the same type of action (a specific parsing of the incoming expression) inside the other command, which should form the contents of the document and can also repeatedly occur in the body of the document or the third command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_opt_number_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \parsecommand #1#2#3#4#5 {
%\NewDocumentCommand{\parsecommand}{
%   m   % #1 expression to parse
%   m   % #2 */empty
%   m   % #3 +/-/empty
%   m   % #4 part before ! / 1
%   m   % #5 part after ! / empty
%}{
\int_zero:N \l_opt_number_int
\tl_clear:N #2
\tl_clear:N #3
\tl_clear:N #4
\tl_clear:N #5
\tl_if_in:NnTF #1 {!} {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn #1 {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_done_bool
    \tl_case:Nn ##1 {
    * {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 1}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #2 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {1}}}
    - {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 2}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #3 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {2}}}
    + {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 2}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #3 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {2}}}
    ! {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 3}{
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {3}}}
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l_done_bool {
      \int_compare:nTF {\l_opt_number_int < 3}
        {\tl_put_right:Nn #4 {##1}}
        {\tl_put_right:Nn #5 {##1}}
      }
    }
  }
  {\tl_set_eq:NN #5 #1}
  \tl_if_empty:NT #4 {\tl_put_right:Nn #4 {1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\othercommandone}{m}{
    \parsecommand{#1}{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}
    \{#1\} $\rightarrow$ \{\a\}\{\b\}\{\c\}\{\d\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\othercommandtwo}{m}{
\def\incoming{#1}
    \parsecommand{\incoming}{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}
    \{\incoming\} $\rightarrow$ \{\a\}\{\b\}\{\c\}\{\d\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcommandone}{m}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \parsecommand{#1}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \node at (0,\nthy*5mm) {\dlabel};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcommandtwo}{m}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \def\incoming{#1}
    \parsecommand{\incoming}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \node at (0,\nthy*1cm) {\dlabel};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\def\something{*+5!abc}
\def\somethingelse{+777}
\def\somethingmore{-!$\sqrt{\alpha}$}

Directly in the document command works\ldots

\parsecommand{\something}{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}
\{\something\} $\rightarrow$ \{\a\}\{\b\}\{\c\}\{\d\}

\parsecommand{\somethingelse}{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}
\{\somethingelse\} $\rightarrow$ \{\a\}\{\b\}\{\c\}\{\d\}

\parsecommand{\somethingmore}{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}
\{\somethingmore\} $\rightarrow$ \{\a\}\{\b\}\{\c\}\{\d\}
\bigskip

If command is used directly with argument, there are no problems\ldots

\othercommandone{\something}

\othercommandone{\somethingelse}

\othercommandone{\somethingmore}
\bigskip

If command is used via intermediate macro, there are problems\ldots

\othercommandtwo{\something}

\othercommandtwo{\somethingelse}

\othercommandtwo{\somethingmore}
\bigskip

For purity of experiment, application inside \verb|tikzpicture| directly with argument, everything is fine\ldots

\drawcommandone{\something}
\hspace{1cm}
\drawcommandone{\somethingelse}
\hspace{1cm}
\drawcommandone{\somethingmore}
\bigskip

Finally, as it must be, with internal intermediate transformation (it is planned to split comma-separated values), problems arise again\ldots

\drawcommandtwo{\something}
\hspace{1cm}
\drawcommandtwo{\somethingelse}
\hspace{1cm}
\drawcommandtwo{\somethingmore}

\end{document}
```

When using the command in complex situations, various errors occur, including the absence of some values of the parsed expression. The command is used inside the `tikzpicture` inside third command. I wanted it to use, for example, like results of `\pgfgettransformentries`.

[02/05/2017] Example replaced with a more realistic situation. Now it does not work as I want.

[image: Screenshot]

[04/05/2017] Anyway, something escapes my understanding (this is probably unavoidable)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\extractfirst}{mm}{\tl_set:Nx #1 {\clist_item:Nn #2 {1} }}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extractlast}{mm}{\tl_set:Nx #1 {\clist_item:Nn #2 {-1} }}

\int_new:N \l_opt_number_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \parsecommand #1#2#3#4#5 {
%\NewDocumentCommand{\parsecommand}{
%   m   % #1 expression to parse
%   m   % #2 */empty
%   m   % #3 +/-/empty
%   m   % #4 part before ! / 1
%   m   % #5 part after ! / empty
%}{
\int_zero:N \l_opt_number_int
\tl_clear:N #2
\tl_clear:N #3
\tl_clear:N #4
\tl_clear:N #5
\tl_if_in:NnTF #1 {!} {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn #1 {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_done_bool
    \tl_case:Nn ##1 {
    * {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 1}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #2 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {1}}}
    - {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 2}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #3 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {2}}}
    + {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 2}{
        \tl_set_eq:NN #3 ##1
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {2}}}
    ! {\int_compare:nT {\l_opt_number_int < 3}{
        \bool_set_true:N \l_done_bool
        \int_set:Nn \l_opt_number_int {3}}}
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l_done_bool {
      \int_compare:nTF {\l_opt_number_int < 3}
        {\tl_put_right:Nn #4 {##1}}
        {\tl_put_right:Nn #5 {##1}}
      }
    }
  }
  {\tl_set_eq:NN #5 #1}
  \tl_if_empty:NT #4 {\tl_put_right:Nn #4 {1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcommandone}{m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\extractfirst{\frstprt}{#1}
\extractlast{\lstprt}{#1}

\draw (-3,0) -- (-1,0);
\node [anchor=north] at (-2,0) {\frstprt};
\parsecommand{\frstprt}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
\node at (-2,\nthy*4mm) {\dlabel};

\draw (1,0) -- (3,0);
\node [anchor=north] at (2,0) {\lstprt};
\parsecommand{\lstprt}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
\node at (2,\nthy*4mm) {\dlabel};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcommandtwo}{m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\def\incoming{#1}%
\extractfirst{\frstprt}{\incoming}
\extractlast{\lstprt}{\incoming}

\draw (-3,0) -- (-1,0);
\node [anchor=north] at (-2,0) {\frstprt};
\expandafter\parsecommand\expandafter{\frstprt}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
\node at (-2,\nthy*4mm) {\dlabel};

\draw (1,0) -- (3,0);
\node [anchor=north] at (2,0) {\lstprt};
\expandafter\parsecommand\expandafter{\lstprt}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
\node at (2,\nthy*4mm) {\dlabel};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

%\def\something{*+5!first,+2!second}
%\def\something{+777,*!150}
\def\something{3!$\sqrt{\alpha}$,2!$\beta^2$}

\drawcommandone{\something}
\vspace{1cm}

\drawcommandtwo{\something}

\end{document}
```

How to make results match in this case?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Besides that using `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\d` for your variables is a very bad idea, it's quite unclear how you want to use `\parsecommand` in `\pgfgettransformentries`

Comment: I do not want to use them in `\pgfgettransformentries`. I want to use them on the same principles as the results of `\pgfgettransformentries`.

Comment: Well, the obvious problem is that `\something` is not `*+5!abc`, but expands to it. Might you provide an explicit description of the intended action of `\somecommand`?

Comment: I need an exploded expression, the individual elements of which at different places within the command affect different parts of the figure's construction, for example, through conditions, or are used directly for display. Moreover, this operation can be performed repeatedly inside the command. Initially, there was an idea of simple control of the construction of geometric dimensions in the drawing without interfering with the code of the command with a significant change in the configuration of the image. I'll try to make a compact example, but it will take some time.

Comment: I did not see any problem running your code. Is that my problem?

Comment: @Symbol1, when I pulled out the command from the document and made MWE, I also found that it was completely successful. Therefore, I need a more exact example to the real situation. Maybe, while processing it I'll understand what causes problem.

Comment: Example replaced with a more realistic situation. Now does not work as I want.

Comment: `\expandafter\parsecommand\expandafter{\incoming}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told in my comment, you need to expand the argument before `\parsecommand` acts on it:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcommandtwo}{m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \def\incoming{#1}%
    \expandafter\parsecommand\expandafter{\incoming}{\douter}{\danchor}{\nthy}{\dlabel}
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \node at (0,\nthy*5mm) {\dlabel};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I do not use LaTeX often. Although the common principle of tokens expansion is understandable for me, understanding the application of these commands is still a problem. I tried to use it here, but did not think about passed argument in conjunction.